# Vertically align image while breaking out of container

Tags: css, image, vertical-alignment

Okay, so I have various solutions for vertically aligning elements of arbitrary height within a container. All of these work when the content has a height that is smaller than the container.

What if the content height is taller than the container? For example, say I have a container of fixed height 100px. I also have some images of various heights; I need to vertically align these so the center point of the image matches the center point of the container, like so:

(can't upload images as I'm not reputable enough apparently) - example is here: http://gbradley.com/_images/stuff/valign.png

Without specifying the positions of the images manually, how can I achieve this? I feel like I'm missing something quite obvious.

Comment: Could I suggest using some javascript(jQuery) at all ?

Comment: I'm hoping for a CSS-only solution really; I can do it easily enough with JS but would like to avoid doing so if at all possible!

Comment: Don't think there's a pure css way to do it my good man.  Since you want them to break out of the container based on their size you either need to manually enter a top value or let javascript calculate it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need IE lesser than 8 and in standards mode, you can use big negative margin and helper pseudo-element: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/CXRVn/

If you need older IE, you can use another way, using helper element with big height and some positioning quirks: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/CXRVn/5/

There you must set the negative top offset to `.image` equal to the half of the helper's height minus the half of the parent's height. Works in IE6 either :)

Comment: +1 - very nice.  Had no idea something like that was possible.

Comment: Brilliant, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Didn't think about using a pseudo-element, seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Amazing! Here's a version using text and hiding the overflow with a wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/MSUfR/